# Recursos en un archivo .apk

Tags: android, apk

he estado buscando por foros pero en ninguno he encontrado una solución a mi problema. Lo que pretendo hacer es cambiar las animaciones de un archivo `.apk` por otras. He estado buscando con el analizador de apk de *Android Studio* Pero no he encontrado ningún archivo .gif/.mp4, ni siquiera encontré archivos de sonido. Aquí les dejo lo que contenía el archivo `.apk`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Los recursos se deben encontrar dentro del directorio `/src` ahì puedes encontrar las imagenes, layouts, etc.

> Los recursos de la app, como mapas de bits y diseños, se organizan en
> directorios específicos de tipo dentro del directorio res/ de cada
> módulo.

Dentro de `/assets` pueden almacenarse tambièn archivos de multimedia como audio y video por ejemplo los .mp4

Revisa:

[Cómo agregar recursos de la app](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources)